# I can't open my PBIX file, ExecuteXmla failed with result

Tags: powerbi

I tried to update the latest version of power bi bu it won't work for me.  I worked hours upon hours on a file and it won't open. please help.

Pleae find the attached error below for refernce :-

```
Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)

Error Message:
ExecuteXmla failed with result

Stack Trace:
Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.AnalysisServices.XmlaExecutionException
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.AnalysisServices.AnalysisServicesService.ExecuteXmla(String xmla)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.AnalysisServices.AnalysisServicesService.<>c__DisplayClass45_0.<ImageLoadDatabaseFromPbix>b__0()
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.AnalysisServices.AnalysisServicesService.OnErrorClarify(Action action, String clarification)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.IExceptionHandlerExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<HandleExceptionsWithNestedTasks>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)

Stack Trace Message:
ExecuteXmla failed with result

Invocation Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.StackTraceInfo..ctor(String exceptionStackTrace, String invocationStackTrace, String exceptionMessage)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Telemetry.PowerBIUserFeedbackServices.GetStackTraceInfo(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Telemetry.PowerBIUserFeedbackServices.ReportException(IWindowHandle activeWindow, IUIHost uiHost, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e, Boolean useGDICapture)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<HandleException>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)


PowerBINonFatalError:
{"AppName":"PBIDesktop","AppVersion":"2.97.861.0","ModuleName":"Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.dll","Component":"Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.AnalysisServices.AnalysisServicesService","Error":"Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.AnalysisServices.XmlaExecutionException - PFE_M_ENGINE_INTERNAL,PFE_METADATA_LOAD_FAILED","MethodDef":"ExecuteXmla - PFE_M_ENGINE_INTERNAL,PFE_METADATA_LOAD_FAILED","ErrorOffset":"112"}

InnerException0.Stack Trace Message:
M Engine error: 'Microsoft.Data.Mashup; The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Mashup.MashupConnection' threw an exception.'.
An error occurred when loading the 'dcc69860-2164-43a9-80d1-c6551e32a271', from the file, '\\?\C:\Users\Deepak.Kumar\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop Store App\AnalysisServicesWorkspaces\AnalysisServicesWorkspace_4807a1a9-2f4e-4478-90c8-71d863f24970\Data\dcc69860-2164-43a9-80d1-c6551e32a271.0.db.xml'.


InnerException0.Stack Trace:


InnerException0.Invocation Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromException(Exception e, String prefix)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromInnerExceptions(Exception e, Int32 depth)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.CreateAdditionalErrorInfo(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String message, Exception exception, Nullable`1 stackTraceInfo, String messageDetail)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Telemetry.PowerBIUserFeedbackServices.ReportException(IWindowHandle activeWindow, IUIHost uiHost, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e, Boolean useGDICapture)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<HandleException>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)


PowerBINonFatalError_ErrorDescription:
PFE_M_ENGINE_INTERNAL,PFE_METADATA_LOAD_FAILED

PowerBINonFatalError_MethodDefDescription:
PFE_M_ENGINE_INTERNAL,PFE_METADATA_LOAD_FAILED

PowerBIUserFeedbackServices_IsReported:
True
```

Thanks in advance. please some way to open my pbix file.

Comment: Does this file work before? What did you do in meantime?

Comment: anything i just added some linechart, candle charts and simple measure.

Comment: Have you tried the latest / earlier version of the powerbi? ( You can find it here)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/desktop-latest-update-archive?tabs=powerbi-desktop

Comment: it is working now.. thanks @msta42a